# For ethernet with bandwidth B, how much time a node has to wait before sensing the channel after the first collision detected?

Tags: ethernet, network, networking, access-control

Let's say one node detected a collision at t=0, in B Mbps ethernet, how long will that node wait before sensing the channel again?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

Nodes back off a random amount of time after a collision before trying to transmit. This prevents all the nodes from trying to transmit at the same time after a collision, causing another collision.